# new action trying to use show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here are my routes:

```
equipment_index GET    /equipment(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"equipment"}
            POST   /equipment(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"equipment"}
new_equipment GET    /equipment/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"equipment"}
edit_equipment GET    /equipment/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"equipment"}
equipment GET    /equipment/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"equipment"}
            PUT    /equipment/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"equipment"}
            DELETE /equipment/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"equipment"}
categories GET    /categories(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"categories"}
            POST   /categories(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"categories"}
new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"categories"}
edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"categories"}
category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}
            PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"categories"}
            DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"categories"}
```

When I go to http://localhost:3000/equipment/new I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"equipment"}
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Equipmentmanager::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :equipment
  resources :categories
end
```

Everything else are set to the defaults, except that I used nifty:scaffold.

This is in 3.1, but it does it in 3.0 also
I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: Where are the routes defined that you first mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So localhost:3000/equipment/new is getting routed with this line:

```
equipment GET /equipment/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"equipment"}
```

As it should be. Since you want it to actually go to the new route you need to call localhost:3000/new_equipment since you have defined that route.

As a bit cleaner syntax if you wanted localhost:3000/new_equipment to route to the new action you could put this line in your routes.rb file (above the resources :equipment line since its more specific):

```
get "new_equipment" => "equipment#new", :as => "new_equipment"
```

That line will also define helpers that give you access to new_equipment_path and new_equipment_url

Comment: Am I missing something with this?  That is the default route in there, shouldn't rails be able to handle that?  I have another scaffold called category and it works find with the default route for it.  Is it because the plural is the same as the singular?  That is the only difference I can see.

Comment: In what order are your routes defined? Is the resources :equipment below the other mentioned routes?

Comment: the equipment was the only one, then I added the other when this answer was given. To answer your quetions: No even now the equipment is the top one

Comment: I added the category route to the original question to show the change

Comment: I found the error and it wasn't even that issue, it was equipment_path in in the new view.  I guess that doesn't work in rails 3 or 3.1.  It is a singular vs plural issue.

Comment: Hmm weird... but at least you got it figured out!