# 'show' route matched instead 'new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

rails 3.1

**rake routes** for admin/sections_contoller

```
trigger_admin_section GET    /admin/sections/:id/trigger(.:format)    {:action=>"trigger", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
       admin_sections GET    /admin/sections(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
                      POST   /admin/sections(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
    new_admin_section GET    /admin/sections/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
   edit_admin_section GET    /admin/sections/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
        admin_section GET    /admin/sections/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
                      PUT    /admin/sections/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
                      DELETE /admin/sections/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/sections"}
```

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :sections do
    resources :items
    resources :parameters
    get :trigger, :on => :member
  end
...
end
```

**view**

```
<%= link_to "Add a section", new_admin_section_path, :class=>'add-btn' %>
```

**generated link**

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/sections/new
```

**result**

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/sections", 
                  :id=>#<Section id: nil, ..., meta_description: nil}
```

strange bug or my mistake. other controllers has similar routes and all works fine.
for ex.:

```
 <%= link_to 'Add a group', new_admin_group_path, :class=>'add-btn' %>
```

works GREAT!

please, help or i'll kill myself someday

**upd1** same problem on heroku with this app.

**upd2** join github issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer.

once i put this string in view 'admin/section/_form'

```
<%= link_to 'delete', admin_section_path(@section), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Sure?" %>
```

i used this form for creating and editing. so combination of new object and deleting link for it caused the bug. 
i used debugger for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your "create" method in sections_controller.

I guess your section is correctly created but it redirect to "show" action. And "show" view may not exist.

Have you checked your database ? Is the section saved ?

Comment: I may have read your question a little bit quick. I thought it was a form, not a link. Have you checked this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482274/new-action-trying-to-use-show

Comment: Have you tried to try something like this : <%= link_to "Add a section", :controller => "sections", :action => "new", :class=>'add-btn' %> ? Is it the same problem ?

Comment: try "/admin/:id/sections/new" ?